# How could I add an overlay to a video based on mouse cursor coordinates?

Tags: javascript, ffmpeg

I am making a web app, where the user clicks through some images while talking about them and pointing things out with the cursor. The audio, timestamps of image changes, and mouse cursor coordinates and times are sent to a php script which uses ffmpeg to make a slideshow from the images and audio.

Then it runs another ffmpeg command to overlay a moving image representing the cursor hundreds of times to mimic the user's mouse movements.

Here is an example command that inserts the mouse overlay:

```bash
ffmpeg \
  -i ../tmp/6400d9c21a62d.mp4 \
  -i ../assets/mouse-circle.png \
  -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v]overlay=enable='between=(t,0.627,0.874)':x=777.648+(t-0.627)*0.000/0.247:y=937.572+(t-0.627)*0.000/0.247[a1]; \
    [a1][1:v]overlay=enable='between=(t,0.874,0.914)':x=777.648+(t-0.874)*0.000/0.040:y=937.572+(t-0.874)*-1.223/0.040[a2]; \
    [a2][1:v]overlay=enable='between=(t,0.914,0.936)':x=777.648+(t-0.914)*0.000/0.022:y=936.349+(t-0.914)*0.000/0.022[a3]; \
    [a3][1:v]overlay=enable='between=(t,0.936,0.945)':x=777.648+(t-0.936)*0.000/0.009:y=936.349+(t-0.936)*-1.223/0.009[a4]; \
    [a4][1:v]overlay=enable='between=(t,0.945,0.966)':x=777.648+(t-0.945)*0.000/0.021:y=935.127+(t-0.945)*-1.223/0.021[a5]; \
    [a5][1:v]overlay=enable='between=(t,0.966,0.976)':x=777.648+(t-0.966)*0.000/0.010:y=933.904+(t-0.966)*-1.223/0.010[a6]; \
    [a6][1:v]overlay=enable='between=(t,0.976,0.999)':x=777.648+(t-0.976)*0.000/0.023:y=932.682+(t-0.976)*0.000/0.023[a7]; \
    [a7][1:v]overlay=enable='between=(t,0.999,1.019)':x=777.648+(t-0.999)*1.227/0.020:y=932.682+(t-0.999)*-1.223/0.020[a8]; \
    [a8][1:v]overlay=enable='between=(t,1.019,1.039)':x=778.875+(t-1.019)*0.000/0.020:y=931.459+(t-1.019)*-1.223/0.020[a9]; \
    [a9][1:v]overlay=enable='between=(t,1.039,1.091)':x=778.875+(t-1.039)*0.000/0.052:y=930.236+(t-1.039)*0.000/0.052[a10]; \
    [a10][1:v]overlay=enable='between=(t,1.091,1.142)':x=778.875+(t-1.091)*0.000/0.051:y=930.236+(t-1.091)*-1.223/0.051[a11]; \
    [a11][1:v]overlay=enable='between=(t,1.142,1.152)':x=778.875+(t-1.142)*0.000/0.010:y=929.014+(t-1.142)*-1.223/0.010[a12]; \
    [a12][1:v]overlay=enable='between=(t,1.152,1.161)':x=778.875+(t-1.152)*0.000/0.009:y=927.791+(t-1.152)*-1.223/0.009[a13]; \
    [a13][1:v]overlay=enable='between=(t,1.161,1.173)':x=778.875+(t-1.161)*2.454/0.012:y=926.569+(t-1.161)*-3.668/0.012[a14]; \
    [a14][1:v]overlay=enable='between=(t,1.173,1.184)':x=781.329+(t-1.173)*0.000/0.011:y=922.901+(t-1.173)*-8.558/0.011[a15]; \
    [a15][1:v]overlay=enable='between=(t,1.184,1.193)':x=781.329+(t-1.184)*0.000/0.009:y=914.343+(t-1.184)*-4.890/0.009[a16]; \
    [a16][1:v]overlay=enable='between=(t,1.193,1.203)':x=781.329+(t-1.193)*0.000/0.010:y=909.452+(t-1.193)*-3.668/0.010[a17]; \
    [a17][1:v]overlay=enable='between=(t,1.203,1.213)':x=781.329+(t-1.203)*0.000/0.010:y=905.784+(t-1.203)*-8.558/0.010[a18]; \
    [a18][1:v]overlay=enable='between=(t,1.213,1.223)':x=781.329+(t-1.213)*0.000/0.010:y=897.226+(t-1.213)*-4.890/0.010[a19]; \
    [a19][1:v]overlay=enable='between=(t,1.223,1.234)':x=781.329+(t-1.223)*0.000/0.011:y=892.336+(t-1.223)*-3.668/0.011[a20]; \
    [a20][1:v]overlay=enable='between=(t,1.234,1.246)':x=781.329+(t-1.234)*0.000/0.012:y=888.668+(t-1.234)*-8.558/0.012[a21]; \
    [a21][1:v]overlay=enable='between=(t,1.246,1.256)':x=781.329+(t-1.246)*0.000/0.010:y=880.110+(t-1.246)*-3.668/0.010[a22]; \
    [a22][1:v]overlay=enable='between=(t,1.256,1.265)':x=781.329+(t-1.256)*0.000/0.009:y=876.442+(t-1.256)*-4.890/0.009[a23]; \
    [a23][1:v]overlay=enable='between=(t,1.265,1.282)':x=781.329+(t-1.265)*0.000/0.017:y=871.551+(t-1.265)*-8.558/0.017[a24]; \
    [a24][1:v]overlay=enable='between=(t,1.282,1.298)':x=781.329+(t-1.282)*1.227/0.016:y=862.993+(t-1.282)*-8.558/0.016[a25]; \
    [a25][1:v]overlay=enable='between=(t,1.298,1.316)':x=782.556+(t-1.298)*0.000/0.018:y=854.435+(t-1.298)*-8.558/0.018[a26]; \
    [a26][1:v]overlay=enable='between=(t,1.316,1.331)':x=782.556+(t-1.316)*2.454/0.015:y=845.877+(t-1.316)*-8.558/0.015[a27]; \
    [a27][1:v]overlay=enable='between=(t,1.331,1.349)':x=785.010+(t-1.331)*0.000/0.018:y=837.318+(t-1.331)*-3.668/0.018[a28]; \
    [a28][1:v]overlay=enable='between=(t,1.349,1.365)':x=785.010+(t-1.349)*2.454/0.016:y=833.651+(t-1.349)*-13.449/0.016[a29]; \
    [a29][1:v]overlay=enable='between=(t,1.365,1.382)':x=787.464+(t-1.365)*3.681/0.017:y=820.202+(t-1.365)*-13.449/0.017[a30]; \
    [a30][1:v]overlay=enable='between=(t,1.382,1.399)':x=791.145+(t-1.382)*0.000/0.017:y=806.753+(t-1.382)*-8.558/0.017[a31]; \
    [a31][1:v]overlay=enable='between=(t,1.399,1.415)':x=791.145+(t-1.399)*4.908/0.016:y=798.195+(t-1.399)*-13.449/0.016[a32]; \
    [a32][1:v]overlay=enable='between=(t,1.415,1.433)':x=796.053+(t-1.415)*2.454/0.018:y=784.746+(t-1.415)*-17.116/0.018[a33]; \
    [a33][1:v]overlay=enable='between=(t,1.433,1.449)':x=798.507+(t-1.433)*3.681/0.016:y=767.630+(t-1.433)*-8.558/0.016[a34]; \
    [a34][1:v]overlay=enable='between=(t,1.449,1.466)':x=802.188+(t-1.449)*6.135/0.017:y=759.072+(t-1.449)*-18.339/0.017[a35]; \
    [a35][1:v]overlay=enable='between=(t,1.466,1.482)':x=808.323+(t-1.466)*2.454/0.016:y=740.733+(t-1.466)*-8.558/0.016[a36]; \
    [a36][1:v]overlay=enable='between=(t,1.482,1.499)':x=810.777+(t-1.482)*6.135/0.017:y=732.174+(t-1.482)*-18.339/0.017[a37]; \
    [a37][1:v]overlay=enable='between=(t,1.499,1.516)':x=816.912+(t-1.499)*8.589/0.017:y=713.835+(t-1.499)*-14.671/0.017[a38]; \
    [a38][1:v]overlay=enable='between=(t,1.516,1.532)':x=825.501+(t-1.516)*3.681/0.016:y=699.164+(t-1.516)*-8.558/0.016[a39]; \
    [a39][1:v]overlay=enable='between=(t,1.532,1.549)':x=829.181+(t-1.532)*4.908/0.017:y=690.606+(t-1.532)*-13.449/0.017[a40]; \
    [a40][1:v]overlay=enable='between=(t,1.549,1.565)':x=834.089+(t-1.549)*8.589/0.016:y=677.157+(t-1.549)*-14.671/0.016[a41]; \
    [a41][1:v]overlay=enable='between=(t,1.565,1.583)':x=842.678+(t-1.565)*2.454/0.018:y=662.486+(t-1.565)*-8.558/0.018[a42]; \
    [a42][1:v]overlay=enable='between=(t,1.583,1.599)':x=845.132+(t-1.583)*8.589/0.016:y=653.928+(t-1.583)*-14.671/0.016[a43]; \
    [a43][1:v]overlay=enable='between=(t,1.599,1.616)':x=853.721+(t-1.599)*2.454/0.017:y=639.257+(t-1.599)*-4.890/0.017[a44]; \
    [a44][1:v]overlay=enable='between=(t,1.616,1.632)':x=856.175+(t-1.616)*9.816/0.016:y=634.366+(t-1.616)*-18.339/0.016[a45]; \
    [a45][1:v]overlay=enable='between=(t,1.632,1.649)':x=865.991+(t-1.632)*8.589/0.017:y=616.027+(t-1.632)*-14.671/0.017[a46]; \
    [a46][1:v]overlay=enable='between=(t,1.649,1.666)':x=874.580+(t-1.649)*6.135/0.017:y=601.356+(t-1.649)*-9.781/0.017[a47]; \
    [a47][1:v]overlay=enable='between=(t,1.666,1.682)':x=880.715+(t-1.666)*8.589/0.016:y=591.575+(t-1.666)*-14.671/0.016[a48]; \
    [a48][1:v]overlay=enable='between=(t,1.682,1.699)':x=889.303+(t-1.682)*8.589/0.017:y=576.904+(t-1.682)*-14.671/0.017[a49]; \
    [a49][1:v]overlay=enable='between=(t,1.699,1.716)':x=897.892+(t-1.699)*6.135/0.017:y=562.232+(t-1.699)*-4.890/0.017[a50]; \
    [a50][1:v]overlay=enable='between=(t,1.716,1.732)':x=904.027+(t-1.716)*8.589/0.016:y=557.342+(t-1.716)*-14.671/0.016[a51]; \
    [a51][1:v]overlay=enable='between=(t,1.732,1.749)':x=912.616+(t-1.732)*7.362/0.017:y=542.671+(t-1.732)*-9.781/0.017[a52]; \
    [a52][1:v]overlay=enable='between=(t,1.749,1.766)':x=919.978+(t-1.749)*8.589/0.017:y=532.890+(t-1.749)*-14.671/0.017[a53]; \
    [a53][1:v]overlay=enable='between=(t,1.766,1.782)':x=928.567+(t-1.766)*4.908/0.016:y=518.219+(t-1.766)*-4.890/0.016[a54]; \
    [a54][1:v]overlay=enable='between=(t,1.782,1.799)':x=933.475+(t-1.782)*8.589/0.017:y=513.328+(t-1.782)*-11.003/0.017[a55]; \
    [a55][1:v]overlay=enable='between=(t,1.799,1.815)':x=942.063+(t-1.799)*7.362/0.016:y=502.325+(t-1.799)*-9.781/0.016[a56]; \
    [a56][1:v]overlay=enable='between=(t,1.815,1.832)':x=949.425+(t-1.815)*6.135/0.017:y=492.544+(t-1.815)*-4.890/0.017[a57]; \
    [a57][1:v]overlay=enable='between=(t,1.832,1.849)':x=955.560+(t-1.832)*6.135/0.017:y=487.654+(t-1.832)*-7.336/0.017[a58]; \
    [a58][1:v]overlay=enable='between=(t,1.849,1.866)':x=961.695+(t-1.849)*6.135/0.017:y=480.318+(t-1.849)*-3.668/0.017[a59]; \
    [a59][1:v]overlay=enable='between=(t,1.866,1.883)':x=967.830+(t-1.866)*1.227/0.017:y=476.650+(t-1.866)*-1.223/0.017[a60]; \
    [a60][1:v]overlay=enable='between=(t,1.883,1.900)':x=969.057+(t-1.883)*8.589/0.017:y=475.427+(t-1.883)*-2.445/0.017[a61]; \
    [a61][1:v]overlay=enable='between=(t,1.900,1.916)':x=977.646+(t-1.900)*6.135/0.016:y=472.982+(t-1.900)*-1.223/0.016[a62]; \
    [a62][1:v]overlay=enable='between=(t,1.916,1.933)':x=983.781+(t-1.916)*1.227/0.017:y=471.760+(t-1.916)*0.000/0.017[a63]; \
    [a63][1:v]overlay=enable='between=(t,1.933,1.949)':x=985.008+(t-1.933)*1.227/0.016:y=471.760+(t-1.933)*0.000/0.016[a64]; \
    [a64][1:v]overlay=enable='between=(t,1.949,1.966)':x=986.235+(t-1.949)*1.227/0.017:y=471.760+(t-1.949)*0.000/0.017[a65]; \
    [a65][1:v]overlay=enable='between=(t,1.966,1.983)':x=987.462+(t-1.966)*2.454/0.017:y=471.760+(t-1.966)*0.000/0.017[a66]; \
    [a66][1:v]overlay=enable='between=(t,1.983,2.000)':x=989.916+(t-1.983)*0.000/0.017:y=471.760+(t-1.983)*0.000/0.017[a67]; \
    [a67][1:v]overlay=enable='between=(t,2.000,2.016)':x=989.916+(t-2.000)*0.000/0.016:y=471.760+(t-2.000)*1.223/0.016[a68]; \
    [a68][1:v]overlay=enable='between=(t,2.016,2.033)':x=989.916+(t-2.016)*2.454/0.017:y=472.982+(t-2.016)*2.445/0.017[a69]; \
    [a69][1:v]overlay=enable='between=(t,2.033,2.050)':x=992.370+(t-2.033)*0.000/0.017:y=475.427+(t-2.033)*1.223/0.017[a70]; \
    [a70][1:v]overlay=enable='between=(t,2.050,2.066)':x=992.370+(t-2.050)*2.454/0.016:y=476.650+(t-2.050)*8.558/0.016[a71]; \
    [a71][1:v]overlay=enable='between=(t,2.066,2.082)':x=994.824+(t-2.066)*0.000/0.016:y=485.208+(t-2.066)*7.336/0.016[a72]; \
    [a72][1:v]overlay=enable='between=(t,2.082,2.100)':x=994.824+(t-2.082)*0.000/0.018:y=492.544+(t-2.082)*4.890/0.018[a73]; \
    [a73][1:v]overlay=enable='between=(t,2.100,2.116)':x=994.824+(t-2.100)*3.681/0.016:y=497.434+(t-2.100)*13.449/0.016[a74]; \
    [a74][1:v]overlay=enable='between=(t,2.116,2.134)':x=998.504+(t-2.116)*0.000/0.018:y=510.883+(t-2.116)*7.336/0.018[a75]; \
    [a75][1:v]overlay=enable='between=(t,2.134,2.150)':x=998.504+(t-2.134)*0.000/0.016:y=518.219+(t-2.134)*8.558/0.016[a76]; \
    [a76][1:v]overlay=enable='between=(t,2.150,2.167)':x=998.504+(t-2.150)*0.000/0.017:y=526.777+(t-2.150)*17.116/0.017[a77]; \
    [a77][1:v]overlay=enable='between=(t,2.167,2.183)':x=998.504+(t-2.167)*-7.362/0.016:y=543.893+(t-2.167)*24.452/0.016[a78]; \
    [a78][1:v]overlay=enable='between=(t,2.183,2.200)':x=991.143+(t-2.183)*0.000/0.017:y=568.345+(t-2.183)*8.558/0.017[a79]; \
    [a79][1:v]overlay=enable='between=(t,2.200,2.217)':x=991.143+(t-2.200)*-6.135/0.017:y=576.904+(t-2.200)*23.229/0.017[a80]; \
    [a80][1:v]overlay=enable='between=(t,2.217,2.233)':x=985.008+(t-2.217)*-3.681/0.016:y=600.133+(t-2.217)*14.671/0.016[a81]; \
    [a81][1:v]overlay=enable='between=(t,2.233,2.251)':x=981.327+(t-2.233)*-12.270/0.018:y=614.804+(t-2.233)*36.678/0.018[a82]; \
    [a82][1:v]overlay=enable='between=(t,2.251,2.267)':x=969.057+(t-2.251)*-3.681/0.016:y=651.483+(t-2.251)*14.671/0.016[a83]; \
    [a83][1:v]overlay=enable='between=(t,2.267,2.284)':x=965.376+(t-2.267)*-12.270/0.017:y=666.154+(t-2.267)*36.678/0.017[a84]; \
    [a84][1:v]overlay=enable='between=(t,2.284,2.301)':x=953.106+(t-2.284)*-15.951/0.017:y=702.832+(t-2.284)*31.788/0.017[a85]; \
    [a85][1:v]overlay=enable='between=(t,2.301,2.317)':x=937.156+(t-2.301)*-7.362/0.016:y=734.620+(t-2.301)*14.671/0.016[a86]; \
    [a86][1:v]overlay=enable='between=(t,2.317,2.334)':x=929.794+(t-2.317)*-14.724/0.017:y=749.291+(t-2.317)*25.675/0.017[a87]; \
    [a87][1:v]overlay=enable='between=(t,2.334,2.350)':x=915.070+(t-2.334)*-7.362/0.016:y=774.966+(t-2.334)*15.894/0.016[a88]; \
    [a88][1:v]overlay=enable='between=(t,2.350,2.367)':x=907.708+(t-2.350)*-14.724/0.017:y=790.859+(t-2.350)*25.675/0.017[a89]; \
    [a89][1:v]overlay=enable='between=(t,2.367,2.384)':x=892.984+(t-2.367)*-18.405/0.017:y=816.534+(t-2.367)*20.784/0.017[a90]; \
    [a90][1:v]overlay=enable='between=(t,2.384,2.400)':x=874.580+(t-2.384)*-6.135/0.016:y=837.318+(t-2.384)*11.003/0.016[a91]; \
    [a91][1:v]overlay=enable='between=(t,2.400,2.418)':x=868.445+(t-2.400)*-11.043/0.018:y=848.322+(t-2.400)*9.781/0.018[a92]; \
    [a92][1:v]overlay=enable='between=(t,2.418,2.434)':x=857.402+(t-2.418)*-9.816/0.016:y=858.103+(t-2.418)*8.558/0.016[a93]; \
    [a93][1:v]overlay=enable='between=(t,2.434,2.451)':x=847.586+(t-2.434)*-6.135/0.017:y=866.661+(t-2.434)*4.890/0.017[a94]; \
    [a94][1:v]overlay=enable='between=(t,2.451,2.467)':x=841.451+(t-2.451)*-8.589/0.016:y=871.551+(t-2.451)*4.890/0.016[a95]; \
    [a95][1:v]overlay=enable='between=(t,2.467,2.484)':x=832.862+(t-2.467)*-1.227/0.017:y=876.442+(t-2.467)*1.223/0.017[a96]; \
    [a96][1:v]overlay=enable='between=(t,2.484,2.501)':x=831.635+(t-2.484)*-6.135/0.017:y=877.664+(t-2.484)*3.668/0.017[a97]; \
    [a97][1:v]overlay=enable='between=(t,2.501,2.517)':x=825.501+(t-2.501)*-8.589/0.016:y=881.332+(t-2.501)*2.445/0.016[a98]; \
    [a98][1:v]overlay=enable='between=(t,2.517,2.535)':x=816.912+(t-2.517)*-2.454/0.018:y=883.777+(t-2.517)*1.223/0.018[a99]; \
    [a99][1:v]overlay=enable='between=(t,2.535,2.551)':x=814.458+(t-2.535)*-2.454/0.016:y=885.000+(t-2.535)*2.445/0.016[a100]; \
    [a100][1:v]overlay=enable='between=(t,2.551,2.567)':x=812.004+(t-2.551)*-1.227/0.016:y=887.445+(t-2.551)*0.000/0.016[a101]; \
    [a101][1:v]overlay=enable='between=(t,2.567,2.584)':x=810.777+(t-2.567)*-1.227/0.017:y=887.445+(t-2.567)*0.000/0.017[a102]; \
    [a102][1:v]overlay=enable='between=(t,2.584,2.600)':x=809.550+(t-2.584)*0.000/0.016:y=887.445+(t-2.584)*0.000/0.016[a103]; \
    [a103][1:v]overlay=enable='between=(t,2.600,2.617)':x=809.550+(t-2.600)*-1.227/0.017:y=887.445+(t-2.600)*0.000/0.017[a104]; \
    [a104][1:v]overlay=enable='between=(t,2.617,2.689)':x=808.323+(t-2.617)*0.000/0.072:y=887.445+(t-2.617)*0.000/0.072[a105] \
     \
  " -map "[a105]" -map 0:a:? ../tmp/vid-6400d9c21a62d.mp4 -y
```

And this is just from a four second video. When I tried to do thirty seconds worth of mouse movements, the command would not even run because there were too many arguments. So I need to come up with another way to add a mouse overlay.

An obvious choice would just be screen recording the user's screen to not have to add a mouse overlay because it would already be there. But then I don't think I can use full resolution pictures in the final video. It will be recordings of the images at whatever resolution the user's screen is set to. (Unless there's a way around this that I don't know about.)

So how could I take a long list of mouse coordinates and timestamps and add an overlay representing a cursor to an existing video?

Edit: I tried putting everything from the `filter-complex` argument into a text file and calling it with `filter_complex_script` instead, as @БаярГончикжапов suggested in comments. Now it at least starts to run, but every time fails with this error:

```
[Parsed_overlay_1553 @ 0x55caae67f900] [framesync @ 0x55caae6802a8] Sync level 2
[auto_scale_1554 @ 0x55cab4b34b80] Failed to configure output pad on auto_scale_1554
Error reinitializing filters!
Failed to inject frame into filter network: Resource temporarily unavailable
Error while processing the decoded data for stream #1:0
[AVIOContext @ 0x55cab451c900] Statistics: 0 bytes written, 0 seeks, 0 writeouts
[aac @ 0x55cab4523b80] Qavg: 25282.062
[aac @ 0x55cab4523b80] 2 frames left in the queue on closing
```

It only happens if there are more than 1553 arguments, and changing the arguments for 1553 and surrounding ones doesn't stop the error.

Comment: use `-filter_complex_script file.txt`

Comment: @БаярГончикжапов I tried it and it gave me an error, which I added to the post above.

Comment: RAM is not enough. 16gb for me does error on 4716 args and video converts by speed=0.0313x, so better to split video to 2 sec parts

Comment: @БаярГончикжапов Oh ok, splitting it is a good idea, thanks. Interesting that I have 16GB too but the limit is lower for me.